# How do i do a join query in mysql on this scheme

Tags: mysql, join

I'm having some trouble trying to get all the data out of this database in one query.

Here is the [Database scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEuLd.png)

I know that there is a way to do this with a join but i'm not sure how. 
I need all the data from Questionnaire, Booking, and Customers.
I think i have to join on the Booking has customers but i'm not sure.

At the moment i have something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Booking,Questionaires,Customers 
WHERE accepted = 0 
JOIN ON Booking_idBooking = Customers_idCustomers
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results *in the question*.  What information do you want to extract?

Comment: It's unclear what result you exactly want. And also too broad, as you are not showing us any code.

Comment: I need all the data from Questionaires, Customers and Booking.  But i'm not sure how to join these together. I've been trying with a `SELECT * FROM Booking,Questionaires,Customers  WHERE accepted = 0 JOIN ON Booking_idBooking = Customers_idCustomers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use inner join this way

```
SELECT * FROM Booking_idBooking as BB
INNER JOIN  Booking as B on BB.Booking_idBooking = B.idBooking
INNER JOIN  Customers as C on BB.Customers_idCustomers = C.idCustomers
INNER JOIN  Questionaires as Q on Q.idQuestionaires = B.uestionaires_idQuestionaires
WHERE B.accepted = 0 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go about doing something like this, but you may need left joins depending one your circumstances.

```
select 
  *
from
  customers c

  inner join booking_has_customers bhs on
    bhs.Customers_idCustomers = c.idCustomers

  inner join booking b on
    b.idBooking = booking_idBooking

  inner join Questionaires q on
    q.idQuestionaires = b.Questionairs_idQuestionairs
where
  b.accepted = 0;
```

Just a note, you should really change your naming conventions.

For example `booking` is singular, yet `customers` is plural in your schema. They should be consistent. Also, something like `idBooking` and `booking_idBooking` is not great - maybe use `id` and `booking_id`. Anyway just suggestions.

You also might want to invest some time in learning how to write joins. Checkout [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) for good examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.*,q.*,c.*
FROM Booking AS b
JOIN Questionaries AS q ON q.idQuestionaries=b.Questionaries_idQuestionaries
JOIN Booking_has_Customers AS bhc ON bhc.Booking_idBooking=b.idBooking
JOIN Customers AS c ON c.idCustomers=bhs.Customers_idCustomers
WHERE b.accepted=0
```

But come on, change ID names into simple id and you'll have:

```
SELECT b.*,q.*,c.*
FROM Booking AS b
JOIN Questionaries AS q ON q.id=b.id
JOIN Booking_has_Customers AS bhc ON bhc.id=b.id
JOIN Customers AS c ON c.id=bhs.id
WHERE b.accepted=0
```